# Why does this Clojure code cause an NPE?

Tags: clojure

The following Clojure code causes an NPE.  It seems from the stacktrace this is caused when `>=` is called.  I can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

```
(def service-thresholds
  [{:service "cpu idle" :invert true :warning 50 :critital 10}
   {:service "cpu user" :invert false :warning 80 :critical 90}])

(defn threshold-check
  [thresholds]
  (fn [e]
    (or (first (for [threshold thresholds
                     :when (= (:service threshold) (:service e))]
                 (assoc e :state
                        (if (not (:invert threshold))
                          (condp <= (:metric e)
                            (:critical threshold) "critical"
                            (:warning threshold) "warning"
                            "ok")
                          (condp >= (:metric e)
                            (:critical threshold) "critical"
                            (:warning threshold) "warning"
                            "ok")))))
        e)))

(println ((threshold-check service-thresholds) {:service "cpu idle" :metric 20 :state nil}))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:critital` is not a correct spelling of `:critical`.

Comment: You are so right!  How did I not see that!  Thank you.